# How to access a Google Firestore collection from within a Cloud Function referencing a different Firestore collection?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

The following (from a React site) is not working . I've been in the docs for hours without success. Any ideas?

```
import firebase = require("../../node_modules/firebase");
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

exports.onSomeCollectionCreate = functions
    .firestore
    .document("some-collection/{someCollectionId}")
    .onCreate(async(snap, context) => {
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("another-collection/{anotherCollectionId}")
            .add({ some: "data" });
    }
);
```

Some terminal feedback:

```
⚠  functions[onSomeCollectionCreate(region)]: Deployment error.
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Cloud Function, you should use the Admin SDK in order to interact with the Firebase services, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app) for more details.

The following should therefore work:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.onSomeCollectionCreate = functions
    .firestore
    .document("some-collection/{someCollectionId}")
    .onCreate(async(snap, context) => {
        return admin.   // note the return
            .firestore()
            .collection("another-collection")
            .add({ some: "data" });
    }
);
```

---

Note two additional points:

1. You should not pass to the c`ollection()` method a string with a slash (`/`), since Collection references must have an odd number of segments.
2. Note that we return the Promise returned by the `add()` method. See the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details on this key point.

Comment: thanks renaud. i wish the docs were clearer. "These lines load the firebase-functions and firebase-admin modules, and initialize an admin app instance from which Cloud Firestore changes can be made. Wherever Admin SDK support is available, as it is for FCM, Authentication, and Firebase Realtime Database, it provides a powerful way to integrate Firebase using Cloud Functions." is not clear, and is, stylistically speaking, marketing prose rather than technical documentation.

Comment: I suppose Google is a business first and foremost, so perhaps marketing prose is what we should expect. Neo-liberal capitalism is such a drag

Comment: Glad I could help you. Note that I've added two extra important remarks. In addition to accepting the answer you may also upvote it if it was helpful, thanks! :-) Concerning your comments on the documentation, honestly I think exactly the opposite :-) The Firebase doc (as for other Google Cloud products) is very well done and detailed. Of course, one needs to take time going through this doc, but IMHO it is normal, because they are complex and rich tools/services. .../...

Comment: .../... If a Cloud Function beginner takes the time to read this ["Get started"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) doc, it will guide him really well, on a step by step mode, in order to write his first Cloud Function. Just my opinion :-)

Comment: It's kind of difficult because I'm working for a company who needs this done yesterday and so don't have time to read the docs line by line like a literature student writing an essay whilst sipping a nice chilled Cabernet Sauvignon. If I told the boss I'm going to be spending the morning carefully going through every line of an online guide I'd probaby get the sack. The docs might well be good if you use them like that, but that embeds assumptions that do not segue well with the reality of many people's working situations. In short: I just needed an answer. Thanks for providing it